# Unable to display uploaded images from tomcat7 webapps using Amazon ec2-instance

Tags: java

I have uploaded my `war` file and database on amazon `ec2-instance`. and trying to display images from tomcat7 webapps on jsp page. I set path `/webapps/images/` in image `src` to display images dynamically.

When I click on upload the images. The images uploaded in path saved in the database. I fetched image path from database. The image is not showing up.

Please help me to solve this.....

Edit

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            if(!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
        throw new ServletException("Content type is not multipart/form-data");
    }
    List<UploadBean> list = new ArrayList<UploadBean>();

    int  count=0;
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<FileItem> fileItemsList = uploader.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator<FileItem> fileItemsIterator = fileItemsList.iterator();
        while(fileItemsIterator.hasNext()){
            FileItem fileItem = fileItemsIterator.next();
            System.out.println("FieldName="+fileItem.getFieldName());
            System.out.println("FileName="+fileItem.getName());
            System.out.println("ContentType="+fileItem.getContentType());
            System.out.println("Size in bytes="+fileItem.getSize());
            File file = new File(request.getServletContext().getAttribute("FILES_DIR")+File.separator+fileItem.getName());
            System.out.println("Absolute Path at server="+file.getAbsolutePath());
           fileItem.write(file);
           SelectImageClass select = new SelectImageClass();
           insertTempExp(fileItem.getName());
           list= select.getUploadedImage();
           request.setAttribute("serv", list);
           request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp").forward(
           request, response);
        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        out.write("Exception in uploading file.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: create a folder within project and then try to reference those images.

Comment: Hi khalid,  its fine but i unable to upload the images in folder within project because i need to display uploaded images

Comment: could you show your code for uploading image

Comment: Hi Khalid,  please see code  below for uploading images

Comment: code  below  in  my last answer

Comment: @IrshadQureshi you need to stop using the answer space for explaining your question. Please read FAQ of SO please.

Answer (score 2):

Show your jsp and java file to find what path you are using to access images from
server.

Simply use this for uploading path

```
    String rootPath=request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    String relativePath="images";  //folder name to save images
    File file = new File(rootPath + File.separator + relativePath);
    if(!file.exists()){ file.mkdirs();}
```

`ctx.setAttribute("FILES_DIR_FILE", file);
    ctx.setAttribute("FILES_DIR", rootPath + File.separator + relativePath);`

and show the image in jsp using
`<image src="images/image_name">`

Comment: Hi sohal, can you please explain little more where i need to put this code    because   String rootPath=request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");  i dont have Request methode in servletListener class

Comment: So use ServletContext , like this 
ServletContext ctx = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
     String rootPath=ctx.getRealPath("/");

Comment: Hi sohal,  i have used this code directly the image folder is created inside the project but i dont have image uploaded and null pointer exception on using  ServletContext ctx = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();

Comment: I did use same code in servlet without any listener and it is working fine for me.

Comment: thank u so much sohal its working  but the previous uploaded images by default get deleted when i run code again now i working on local host

Comment: hi sohal,  its working on local server when i uploaded the war file on amazon ec2-instance getting no result

Comment: and i need to use global folder to store uploaded image that can be shown in another project on same server

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FileLocationContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
        ServletContext ctx = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
        String relativePath = ctx.getInitParameter("/webapps/CovetloFiles.dir");

        File file = new File(rootPath + File.separator + relativePath);
        if(!file.exists()){ file.mkdirs();}
        if(!file1.exists()){ file1.mkdirs();}

        System.out.println("File Directory created to be used for storing files");
        ctx.setAttribute("FILES_DIR_FILE", file);
        ctx.setAttribute("FILES_DIR", rootPath + File.separator + relativePath);
    }

<%
ArrayList<UploadBean> list = (ArrayList<UploadBean>) request.getAttribute("serv"); 
if(list!=null) {
  for(UploadBean upload : list) {
    strGet = upload.getUploadImage();   
%>
<img class="img-responsive" src="/CovetloFiles/<%=upload.getUploadImage()%>" name="imgUrl" alt="prod1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Above using servlet context i set path where the image will get uploaded

Below i have created java class where i get image name from database only images uploaded on above path those name stored in database

i have used :  request.setAttribute("serv",list); list contain all the name from database table

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            if(!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)){
        throw new ServletException("Content type is not multipart/form-data");
    }
             List<UploadBean> list = new ArrayList<UploadBean>();
            //HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
     int  count=0;
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<FileItem> fileItemsList = uploader.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator<FileItem> fileItemsIterator = fileItemsList.iterator();
        while(fileItemsIterator.hasNext()){
            FileItem fileItem = fileItemsIterator.next();
            System.out.println("FieldName="+fileItem.getFieldName());
            System.out.println("FileName="+fileItem.getName());
            System.out.println("ContentType="+fileItem.getContentType());
            System.out.println("Size in bytes="+fileItem.getSize());


            File file = new File(request.getServletContext().getAttribute("FILES_DIR")+File.separator+fileItem.getName());
            System.out.println("Absolute Path at server="+file.getAbsolutePath());
           // out.write("<a href=\"UploadServlet?fileName="+fileItem.getName()+"\">Download <img src=/CovetloFiles/"+fileItem.getName()+"  width=100px height=100px></a>");

            fileItem.write(file);
            SelectImageClass select = new SelectImageClass();
           insertTempExp(fileItem.getName());
           list= select.getUploadedImage();
           request.setAttribute("serv", list);
       request.getRequestDispatcher("/test.jsp").forward(
            request, response); 

        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        out.write("Exception in uploading file.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: if image is being uploaded in file directory and right path in db. try to print the path and then try to access the same path from browser in url path. if your path is OK, get path on Jsp page and then do reference like this <img src="images\\<% fileItem.getname()%>">